# Android AssetManager , writing to property file

Tags: android

This is my first android app so I am quite new to it. I am able to read from a property file but facing problem on writing back to it on the save button in the same activity.

Here is my code

public class ConfigurationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_configuration);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final EditText abc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.abc);
    ...
...
...


//Reading into a activity and displaying it into the user
    try {
        Properties props = new Properties();;

        InputStream inputStream = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("app.properties");
        props.load(inputStream);

        abc.setText(props.getProperty("abc"));
        ...
    ...
    ...

        inputStream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File donot exists");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.e("Exception","IO error");
    }

//On the save button I am trying to write back to properties file
    Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SaveButton);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                Properties props = new Properties();

                props.setProperty("abc", abc.getText().toString());
                ...
        ...
        ...

                props.store(getApplicationContext().getAssets().openFd("app.properties").createOutputStream(), null);

                Intent intent = new Intent(ConfigurationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

                //inputStream.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Log.e("Exception", "File donot exists");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e("Exception","IO error");
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

Now I am getting the data from the property file and displaying it to user but on the save button its giving FileNotFoundException. I looked for other codes on stackoverflow but I wasn't able to solve my problem
Can someone guide my in this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot modify assets or resources at runtime. They are read-only.

Comment: Okay. I didn't know that. So how can I do such a task where I may need to update the configuration taken from the user at runtime? What will be the best way for that ?

Comment: @SanchitSaxena: You would need to save the data to a regular file, probably on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). Use the data in assets either as a starter copy of file for internal storage (copying it there on the first run of your app), or as a fallback for values that you do not find in the file on internal storage.